# Style addresses are broken when use Express Params in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters

I want to get 3 params from URL. But when I use params then style links are broken.

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/technic-service/:droneSerialName?/:droneModelName?/:droneAltModelName?', (req, res) => {
    res.render('technic-service', { params: req.params })
})
```

I'm entering params to URL and URL is: website.com/technic-service/1/1-3/1-3-2

This is the real link of style.css: *website.com/assets/css/style.css*

And this is the broken link of style.css after adding params to URL: *website.com/technic-service/1/1-3/1-3-2/assets/css/style.css*

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style links need to start with `/` and then they will not depend upon the path of the current web page.  So, if you where using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

as your style tag, change it to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
```

This will allow it to still inherit the domain of the current web page, but NOT the path.

Comment: I'm still learning... Thank you, you are the man!